# Auto scroll or End less Scroll in Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing iphone application.
need to display 5 records at a time
and when i reached page end then the next 5 records will need to load using automatic scrolling.

initial 5 records display done.

Scroll not working when i reach page end.

Can any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. my code as follows,

```
myTable.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

    if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'iphone')
    {
        var offset = e.contentOffset.y;
        var height = e.size.height;
        var total = offset + height;
        var theEnd = e.contentSize.height;

        // this condition will check whether the scroll reach end or not?
        if (theEnd == total)
        {
             //call the function once again.
             loadContents();
        }

    }
});
```

I hope... some one will use it.

Answer (score 0):

@Suresh.g

You Can use "ScrollView" with property "contentHeight :Ti.UI.Size (or "Auto")".

When you use "ScrollView" it set default height on your requirement.

You can also enable for
showHorizontalScrollIndicator : true,

for more information read this [blog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.UI.ScrollView)

Comment: i want to view loader icon , when the user reach end of page and the dynamic contents will load automatically.